# figurative usage of "within A of B"

Tags: figurative-language

According to the following sentence, was John in the city?

> John was within a kilometer of the city.

Now let us look at a figurative usage of "within ... of":

> John is within an inch of his life.

According to the sentence, is John still alive? If so, why is this sentence interpreted differently from "John was within a kilometer of the city"?

Comment: The usual form of the metaphor is "[Something happened to John] within an inch of his life" - that is, so as to almost kill him. See [this](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/within+an+inch+of+life).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sentence, John is not in the city.

In the second sentence, John is still alive. The second sentence really means, "John is within an inch of death". It's an idiomatic expression that happens not to mean what it literally says.